# ¿Cómo usar los valores de una columna como índice en un array?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine2

Considérese la siguiente tabla `configuraciones`

```
id |  nombre  |  valor  |  categoria
-----------------------------------------------
1  |   color  |  azul   |  personal
2  |   día    |  martes |  personal
3  |   ciudad |  Limón  |  general
```

Suponga que hay muchas configuraciones más clasificadas por categoría. He tratado ejecutar una consulta que me permita obtener dichas configuraciones:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Configuracion c')
    ->where('c.categoria = ?', $categoria);
```

Todo funciona genial hasta este punto. Pero ¿existe alguna forma de crear una consulta que me devuelva una estructura ordena en categorías? Por ejemplo:

```
$resultado = $q->execute(); 

//la idea acá es usar la columna "nombre" como índice:
$color = $resulSet['color']  

//imprimir el valor de color:
echo $color['valor'];  //debería imprimir "azul"
```

Answer (score 3):

El truco es usar el argumento `INDEX BY`.

#### Query class

El siguiente ejemplo ilustra una sentencia usando [Doctrine Query Language](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$consulta = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT c
    FROM modelos\Configuracion c 
    INDEX BY c.nombre
    WHERE c.category = :category');
$consulta->setParameter('category', 'personal');
```

Especificamos el tipo de resultado como un `Array` para poderle manipular por 
índices:

```
$configuraciones = $consulta->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Mostramos el valor:

```
echo $settings['color']['valor'];  // imprime "azul"
```

#### QueryBuilder

Ejemplo usando el objecto [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

```
$consulta = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$consulta->select('c');
// el tercer argumento indica el índice del eventual resultado
$consulta->from('modelos\Configuracion', 'c', 'c.nombre');  
$configuraciones = $consulta->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Ahora solo se accesa al valor a través de las funciones del objeto:

```
$color = $configuraciones['color'];
$valor = $color->getValor(); // devuelve "azul"
```